# Variable Not Changing In Javascript

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I have a recently started coding in Javascript with the ProcessingJS library. I completed to Khan Academy into to JS course. I have a function, when x and y are on the selected area. It should stop the loop, move x and y, and move the score1X and score1Y to 0 then start the loop. The score1X and score1Y are not moving. The function is called in a draw = function. Thanks a lot!

```
var CreatePoint = function(score1X, score1Y) {
    if (x >= score1X - 10 && x <= score1X + 10 && y >= score1Y - 10 && y <= score1Y + 10){
        noLoop();    
        points ++;
        x -= 10;
        y -= 10;
        score1X = 0;
        score1Y = 0;
        loop();
    }
    else if (points <= 0) {
        ellipse(score1X, score1Y, 20, 20);
    }
};

draw = function() {    
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    text(points + "/5", 20, 20);
    CreatePoint(score1X, score1Y);
    CreatePoint(score2X, score2Y);
    CreatePoint(score3X, score3Y);
    CreatePoint(score4X, score4Y);
    CreatePoint(score5X, score5Y);
};
```

Comment: Can you post your loop() function?

Comment: Ok, I added it to the main post.

Comment: Your `draw()` function is there, but where is the `loop()`?

Comment: @Sub6Resources I think that may be part of Processing.js.

Comment: `score1X` and `score1Y` are local variables because they're function parameters. Assigning to them won't affect the global variables with the same name.

Comment: Javascript function arguments are passed by value, not by reference. Assigning to the parameter variables doesn't affect the caller's variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't affect the caller's variables by assigning to the function parameter variable, because Javascript parameters are passed by reference. You need to return the new values, which the caller can assign to the variables.

```
var CreatePoint = function(score1X, score1Y) {
    if (x >= score1X - 10 && x <= score1X + 10 && y >= score1Y - 10 && y <= score1Y + 10){
        noLoop();    
        points ++;
        x -= 10;
        y -= 10;
        score1X = 0;
        score1Y = 0;
        loop();
    }
    else if (points <= 0) {
        ellipse(score1X, score1Y, 20, 20);
    }
    return [score1X, score1Y];
};

draw = function() {    
    fill(255, 255, 255);
    text(points + "/5", 20, 20);
    var res = CreatePoint(score1X, score1Y);
    score1X = res[0];
    score1Y = res[1];
    res = CreatePoint(score2X, score2Y);
    score2X = res[0];
    score2Y = res[1];
    res = CreatePoint(score3X, score3Y);
    score3X = res[0];
    score3Y = res[1];
    res = CreatePoint(score4X, score4Y);
    score4X = res[0];
    score4Y = res[1];
    res = CreatePoint(score5X, score5Y);
    score5X = res[0];
    score5Y = res[1];
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the whole loop stopped working. I used the println(); function to see where the problem is. It said that score1X, score1Y, etc. was undefined. I forgot to say that a declared them at the start of the program as random(25, 375). Is that the problem?

Comment: I don't know why it would say they're undefined if you declared them as global variables. Reassigning them in the functions doesn't change that.